# segmentation fault when moving std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, move-semantics

The following program crashes with segmention fault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct data
{
  data() : a(random()), b(random()), v({random(), random(), random()}) {}
  data(data&& m) noexcept : a(m.a), b(m.b), v(std::move(m.v)) { }

  long int a;
  long int b;
  std::vector<long int> v;
};

data&& randomize()
{
  srandom(time(0));
  data d;
  d.a = random();
  return std::move(d);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  data d = randomize();
  cout << d.a << " " << d.b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled with g++ version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g test.cpp
```

What am I doing wrong? The problem seems to be in std::vector move constructor, cause everything works fine without it. It looks like data object from randomize() is destroyed when function finishes, but shouldn't it rather be moved to the data object in main first?

Comment: Note that there's no need to return an *rvalue* reference here (even if it were valid to return a reference to a local automatic variable). Function return values are always moved if possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This function:

```
data&& randomize()
{
    // ...
    data d
    // ...
    return std::move(d);
}
```

Returns a reference to a local object which is going to be destroyed when the call returns. Therefore, your program has **Undefined Behavior**. Therefore, the returned reference will be *dangling* by the time the move constructor of `data` is invoked here:

```
data d = randomize();
```

You should return a *value* of type `data`, and you shouldn't explicitly invoke `std::move()`:

```
data randomize()
{
    // ...
    data d
    // ...
    return d;
}
```

This way, you will also give the compiler the opportunity to performed [(Named) Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), possibly resulting in no call to the move constructor at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But will this optimization be always performed  by gcc, or there are some exceptions?

Comment: @PavelDavydov: You're welcome :) It is completely up to the compiler to decide, and you should never rely on the assumption that this elision is or is not performed. You just can't tell. In this case, however, what will happen is that with a sufficiently high optimization level any compiler should elide the call to the move constructor. But again, this is by no means something you should rely on.

Comment: the solution you provided is not valid in general with C++11. with deleted copy constructors it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work and won't depend on compiler optimizations:

```
data randomize()
{
    // ...
    data d
    // ...
    return std::move(d);
}
```

The return value has to be constructed before destruction of local variable d.